# Accessing Data after importing from file

Tags: mysql, import

I'm going to preface this with saying I'm a *complete* newbie at this database stuff before the rolling of the eyes happens, so please be patient with me.

I have an sql dump that I am trying to import and access (running Linux mysql). I created the database...

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE db_name
```

And then tried to import the sql file into the database...

```
mysql -uroot -p db_name < db_import.sql
```

At this point, I don't see any errors and everything *seems* fine, so I assume the import worked. However, I have no idea how to access the imported data because `SELECT * FROM db_name;` returns `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db_name.db_name' doesn't exist`. Similarly for `FROM db_import;`.

I understand that it's looking for a table `db_name` within `db_name`, but where would the imported data go? How can I access it? Did I do the import wrong?

Comment: What does db_import.sql contains.Is it a mysqldump file?

Comment: @AbdulManaf - Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect using mysql cli:

```
mysql -u <username> -p<pass> db_name
```

The following command will show you the imported tables:

```
show tables;
```

Then, access the data:

```
select * from <table_name>;
```

where *table_name* is one of the tables in the *show tables*' output.

Comment: Wow, all I was missing was `show tables;` to figure it out -- thanks! Sorry for the ridiculous question.